# Xcode and other Apple apps keep crashing on startup (macOS Mojave)

Tags: mac, crash, xcode, macos-mojave

I am encountering an issue where every single app by Apple is crasing on startup. I have installed the apps from the App Store, and upon starting them, I get the typical "error message" saying Xcode quit unexpectedly. This happens with Pages, Numbers, Keynote etc. too. Below is the error info (in the pastern link).

https://pastebin.com/khadfaJ5

Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: Had you done any major system changes, such as upgrading the OS, prior to this happening? Is your system running 10.14.2 and have you rebooted recently?

Comment: Note that I am using a virtual machine to run macOS, so no. I have tried rebooting many times.

Comment: That is not at all clear in your question. Please edit your question to include more relevant detail about the platform you are running macOS from, ie Windows, Linux, etc. Note that macOS doesn't really place nice when virtualized.

Answer (score 0):

After macOS Mojave upgrade, I encountered this. And unfortunately the only solution that I found is to reload XCode from App Store from scratch.

After that everything works perfect.

Comment: I have the same situation, just after downloading xcode. Every app stopped working, including App Store. The entire vmdk ready to trash...